# Count a value but below the given id in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

if user wants to fetch the total user_points by passing id 4 then the user_point which will be 4 because id 1,2,3,4 total user_point is 4

So if user wants to fetch the total_points by passing id 6 then the total user_point would be 6 because ids 1,2,3,4,5,6 total user_points is 6

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amount` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_point` smallint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `total` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


INSERT INTO `amount` (`id`, `user_id`, `user_point`, `total`, `paid`) VALUES
(1, 29, 1, 44.00, 44.00),
(2, 29, 1, 125.4, 125.40),
(3, 29, 1, 95.00, 95.00),
(4, 29, 1, 44.00, 44.00),
(5, 29, 1, 94.00, 94.00),
(6, 29, 1, 50.00, 50.00);
```

Help me out please

Comment: Here is my code.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60545

Comment: This query works for me.. SELECT count('user_point') FROM amount WHERE id <= 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) total FROM amount 
WHERE user_id= <userid>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(ID) as count from amount where user_id = <ID>
```

try this query

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(user_point) as tot_point from amount where user_id='29';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Query,

```
SELECT SUM(`user_point`) AS tot_points FROM `amount`
WHERE `user_id`= <userid>;
```